# How to get common IDs in each group from a group by SQL clause?

Tags: sql, group-by, netezza, relational-division

I have data of calls for customers. I want to get those customers between two dates that have activity against every date. They did at least one activity every day. I tried following query.

Following is the query:

```
select date_id , count (distinct customer_id) from usage_analysis 
where usage_direction_type_id = 1
and date_id => 20130608 and date_id <= 20130612
group by date_id
```

That returns:

```
DATE_ID         COUNT
----------------------------
20130608        23451
20130609        9878
20130610        56122   
20130611        7811
20130612        12334
```

But I want to get those customers that are common in each group. It may happen a person who called on 8 June does not exist on the next day. So I only want those customers that exist in every group.

Any idea who can I do that in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the distinct dates for each customer.  Only customers with five distinct dates would then pass the test.  The following provides the list of customers:

```
select customer_id
from usage_analysis 
where usage_direction_type_id = 1 and
      date_id >= 20130608 and date_id <= 20130612
group by customer_id
having count(distinct date_id) = 5
```

Comment: If a user makes an activity on 20130612 only but it will be 5 times then what will happen with your query's output?????

Comment: @RomsJain . . . The query is counting distinct values of `date_id`, so that would count only as one date.  The customer would not appear.

Comment: It does not fetch any record. Seems strange. Does it mean, I don't have any user that did activity every day.

Comment: @TahirAkram . . . I can't speak to contents of your data.  Start with a smaller data range -- just June 8th, then June 8th and 9th, and so on -- and see what the results are returning.

Comment: I understand. Well I tried with even 2 days. But does not bring any data. I see more into my data.

Comment: It works, without any change. Thanks Gordon. I was connected with another DB.

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon Linoff answer should be working fine for your situation. When you tried with 2 days, did you make sure to change the count value from 5 to 2?